# Unable to release GPU memory after training a CNN model using keras

Tags: performance, tensorflow, keras, gpu, conv-neural-network

On a Google Colab notebook with keras(2.2.4) and tensorflow(1.13.1) as a backend, I am trying to tune a CNN, I use a simple and basic table of hyper-parameters and run my tests in a set of loops.
My problem is that I can't free the GPU memory after each iteration and Keras doesn't seem to be able to release GPU memory automatically. So every time I get a **Ressource Exhausted : Out Of Memory (OOM) error**
I did some digging up and run into this function that reassembles different solutions that have been suggested to solve this problem ( didn't work for me though)

```py
for _ in hyper_parameters : 
    Run_model(_)
    reset_keras()
```

my set of hyper parameters being :

```py
IMG_SIZE = 800,1000,3
BATCH_SIZEs = [4,8,16]
EPOCHSs = [5,10,50]
LRs = [0.008,0.01]
MOMENTUMs = [0.04,0.09]
DECAYs = [0.1]
VAL_SPLITs = [0.1]
```

and the function I used to free the GPU memory :

```py
def reset_keras():
    sess = get_session()
    clear_session()
    sess.close()
    sess = get_session()

    try:
        del model # this is from global space - change this as you need
    except:
        pass

    print(gc.collect()) # if it's done something you should see a number being outputted

    # use the same config as you used to create the session
    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 1
    config.gpu_options.visible_device_list = "0"
    set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

The only thing that I didn't fully grasp is the "same config as you used to create your model "(line 14) since with Keras we don't chose explicitly a certain configuration.
I get by for one iteration, some times two, but I can't go beyond. I already tried to change the batch_size and for the moment I am unable to afford for a machine with higher performances.
I am using a custom image generator that inherits from **keras.utils.Sequence**.
I monitor the state of GPU memory using this piece of code :

```
import psutil
import GPUtil as GPU

def printmm():
    GPUs = GPU.getGPUs() 
    gpu = GPUs[0]
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    return(" Util {0:.2f}% ".format(gpu.memoryUtil*100))

print(printmm())
```

Comment: So, does it work for one iteration?

Comment: yes it does, some times it works even for two iterations, and for more detail it never stopped in the middle of an iteration

Comment: delete model del model
Keras.clear_session(). also call  gc.collect() for 5 to 20 times. it will release

Comment: I didn't work, I started suspecting the way I monitor my GPU memory, I have just edited my question to include this specific detail.